# Search and filter by only name with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a search and filter script:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<input class="my-textbox" />
<table id="myTable">
    <tr class="header">
        <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
        <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="name">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="name">Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="no-results" style="display:none;">No results!</div>
<script>
var $block = $(".no-results");
$(".my-textbox").keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
    var isMatch = false;
    $("#myTable tr").each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();
        if (content.toUpperCase().indexOf(value) == -1) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            isMatch = true;
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
    $block.toggle(!isMatch);
});
</script>
```

The question is how to filter results by only names?

(So if I search for 'Alfreds', then display 'Alfreds Futterkiste' and 'Germany', but if I search for 'Germany', then display 'No results!').

Comment: For your problem, I would recommend manipulating a json object from your data. And to apply the array.filter() method on it and to generate the DOM afterwards.

Comment: Also please not that you should never have multiple elements with the same name

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to filter just by the text of the first column like:

```
var content = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();
```

**NOTE 1:** The `id` must be unique in the same document so you may need to replace the duplicate ones by common classes.

**NOTE 2:** It will be better to use the `thead/tbody` tags in your table, check the updated HTML bellow.

**Working sample:**

```js
var $block = $(".no-results");

$(".my-textbox").keyup(function() {
  var value = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
  var isMatch = false;

  $("#myTable tbody tr").each(function() {
    var content = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();

    if (content.toUpperCase().indexOf(value) == -1) {
      $(this).hide();
    } else {
      isMatch = true;
      $(this).show();
    }
  });
  $block.toggle(!isMatch);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="my-textbox" />
<br>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="header">
      <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
      <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Berglunds snabbkop</td>
      <td>Sweden</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="no-results" style="display:none;"> No results!</div>
```

Comment: Welcome, Glad to help.

Comment: One more question. If the table contains duplicate name, how do I write the first result of the duplication? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `var content = $(this).html();` to `var content = $(this).find('.name').html();`.

And please, use classes instead of identical IDs (`id="name"` to `class="name"`).

Do not forget not to loop through your header row by adding `:not(.header)` to your selector.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  var $block = $(".no-results");
  
  $(".my-textbox").keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
    var isMatch = false;
    
    $("#myTable tr:not(.header)").each(function() {
        var content = $(this).find('.name').html();
        
        if (content.toUpperCase().indexOf(value) == -1) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            isMatch = true;
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
    
    $block.toggle(!isMatch);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="my-textbox" />
<table id="myTable">
    <tr class="header">
        <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
        <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="no-results" style="display:none;">No results!</div>
```